# What happens in Kafka when partitions are reassigned (esp. logsizes)?

Tags: apache-kafka

so we're currently trying to use Kafka 0.9 and are pretty much in a proof-of-concept-phase. We've only just started to look into it and are trying to figure out, if it's what we need. There's still quite some learning to do, so please bear with me here :)

The current setup is as follows:

- 3 Kafka brokers on different hosts: zkhost1, zkhost2, zkhost3
- One topic: "myTopic"
- The topic had 4 partitions
- The replication factor was 1
- We have one producer and three consumers, all in the same consumer group "myGroup"

Now I was trying to change the replication factor with the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh script. For this I created the following JSON file:

```
{"version":1,
"partitions":[
    {"topic":"myTopic","partition":0,"replicas":[0,1,2]},
    {"topic":"myTopic","partition":1,"replicas":[0,1,2]},
    {"topic":"myTopic","partition":2,"replicas":[0,1,2]},
    {"topic":"myTopic","partition":3,"replicas":[0,1,2]}
    ]
}
```

...and then executed the script:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zkhost1:2181,zkhost2:2181,zkhost3:2181 --reassignment-json-file increase-replication-factor.json --execute
```

This ran smoothly and after that I got my expected replication:

```
Topic:myTopic   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
```

What I don't understand is, what happened to the partitions during that reassignment. When I looked at the ConsumerOffsetChecker, this is what I saw **before** the reassignment:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group myGroup --zookeeper zkhost1:2181 --topic myTopic

Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
myGroup         myTopic                        0   925230          925230          0               none
myGroup         myTopic                        1   925230          925230          0               none
myGroup         myTopic                        2   925230          925230          0               none
myGroup         myTopic                        3   925230          925230          0               none
```

...and this is what I saw **after** the reassignment:

```
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
myGroup         myTopic                        0   23251           23252           1               none
myGroup         myTopic                        1   41281           41281           0               none
myGroup         myTopic                        2   23260           23260           0               none
myGroup         myTopic                        3   41270           41270           0               none
```

For me this raised a few questions:

- Why is the logSize now heavily reduced? Does the reassignment trigger some cleanup? (we have not set a byte limit)
- Why had all 4 partitions roughly the same size before the reassignment, whereas after the reassignment there's this big difference between partitions 0,2 and 1,3? Shouldn't all partitions of one topic have the same logSize or am I misunderstanding the concept here?
- Can something like this (i.e. reassigning partitions) lead to data loss? (I couldn't see any on our consumer in this case). And if so, is there a way to do this without this risk?

Thanks for your answers and best regards,

/tehK